# Upgrade from 12 to 14 failed with missing python package, now what?

Tags: apt, upgrade, python

do-release-upgrade aborted deep in the process.

The main log file ends with the following. How do I recover this system? (The apt.log file seems boring).

```
2015-03-28 08:30:32,930 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg']'
2015-03-28 08:30:32,930 INFO uname information: 'Linux ciderpress 3.2.0-26-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 17:49:24 UTC 2012 x86_64'
2015-03-28 08:30:32,930 INFO apt version: '1.0.1ubuntu2'
2015-03-28 08:30:32,930 INFO python version: '2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
[GCC 4.8.2]'
2015-03-28 08:30:32,930 INFO release-upgrader version '0.220.3' started
2015-03-28 08:30:32,932 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2015-03-28 08:30:32,995 ERROR not handled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/update-manager-BUP2jL/trusty", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())

  File "/tmp/update-manager-BUP2jL/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 230, in main
    from .DistUpgradeController import DistUpgradeController

  File "/tmp/update-manager-BUP2jL/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 74, in <module>
    from . import sourceslist

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/sourceslist.py", line 35, in <module>
    from apt.deprecation import function_deprecated_by

ImportError: No module named deprecation
```

Comment: failed upgrades can be difficult to fix. It is going to be faster and more reliable to do a fresh install. Your other option might be to file a bug report

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and had a dodgy python-apt package from another source.  I removed those sources from `apt` manually by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` and removing files from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and then doing:

```
apt-get update 
apt-get remove python-apt
apt-get install update-manager-core
```

This last one will reinstall python-apt, which should come from the proper ubtuntu sources.  The upgrade seems to be running fine now.